# Map two associative arrays which have different sizes/keys

Tags: php, arrays, merge, mapping, associative-array

I want to merge 2 arrays together but I want it in a specific way.
The first array are the dates I want to filter with the second array dates.

```
$first = [
    '2022-10-23' => '2022-10-23',
    '2022-10-24' => '2022-10-24',
    '2022-10-25' => '2022-10-25',
    '2022-10-26' => '2022-10-26',
    '2022-10-27' => '2022-10-27',
    '2022-10-28' => '2022-10-28',
    '2022-10-29' => '2022-10-29'
];

$second = [
    '2022-10-24' => [
        'id' => 11,
        'user_id' => 1,
        'notitie' => 'Mag al helemaal niet',
        'datum' => '2022-10-24',
        'user_role' => 'client'
    ],
    '2022-10-26' => [
        'id' => 15,
        'user_id' => 1,
        'notitie' => 26,
        'datum' => '2022-10-26',
        'user_role' => 'client'
    ],
];
```

This is the result I want:

```
Array
(
    [2022-10-23] => Array
        (
            [1] => 
        )

[2022-10-24] => Array
    (
        [id] => 11
        [user_id] => 1
        [notitie] => Mag al helemaal niet 
        [datum] => 2022-10-24
        [user_role] => client
    )
    
[2022-10-25] => Array
    (
        [1] => 
    )

[2022-10-26] => Array
    (
        [id] => 15
        [user_id] => 1
        [notitie] => 26
        [datum] => 2022-10-26
        [user_role] => client
    )

[2022-10-27] => Array
    (
        [1] => 
    )

[2022-10-28] => Array
    (
        [1] => 
    )

[2022-10-29] => Array
    (
        [1] => 
    )

)
```

My coding attempt:

```
if ($agendaButtonInfo == "timeGridWeek"){
    $userNotities = array();
    $dagenTussen = array();

    $period = new DatePeriod(
        new DateTime($agendaDatumBegin),
        new DateInterval('P1D'),
        new DateTime($agendaDatumEinde)
    );

    foreach ($period as $key => $value) {
        $dagenTussen[$value->format('Y-m-d')] =  $value->format('Y-m-d');
    }

    $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT notitie_client.id, notitie_client.user_id, notitie_client.notitie, notitie_client.datum, user.user_role
        FROM (notitie_client 
        INNER JOIN user ON notitie_client.user_id = user.id) 
        WHERE notitie_client.user_id='$userId' AND notitie_client.datum BETWEEN '$agendaDatumBegin' AND '$agendaDatumEinde'
        ORDER BY notitie_client.datum ASC;");
  
    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            /*
            echo "<pre>";
                print_r ($row);
            echo "</pre>";
            */ //$userNotitiess[] = array("datumm" => $row["datum"]);
            $userNotities[$row["datum"]] = array( "id" => $row["id"], "user_id" => $row["user_id"], "notitie" => $row["notitie"], "datum" => $row["datum"], "user_role" => $row["user_role"]);
        }
    }  
    echo "<pre>";
        print_r($dagenTussen);
        echo "<pre>";
            print_r($userNotities);
            /*
            print_r  ($dagenTussen);

            function myfunction($v1,$v2)
            {
                //print_r ($v2);
                if ($v1===$v2["datum"])
                {
                    return "same";
                }else{
                    return "different";
                }
            }
            echo "<pre>";
                print_r(array_map("myfunction",$dagenTussen, $userNotities));
                //print_r(array_merge($dagenTussen,$userNotities));

                /*
                foreach($userNotities as $userNotitie ){
                    echo "<pre>";
                        print_r ($userNotitie);
                    echo "</pre>";
                }
                */
                $testt = array("wesley", "darlon");
                $people = array("Peter", "Joe", "wesley", "darlon");

                //print_r ($userNotities);

                foreach ($userNotities as $notatie){
                    echo "<pre>";
                    $notatieDatum[] = $notatie["datum"];
                }
                print_r ($notatieDatum);

                $eindArray = array();
                foreach ($dagenTussen as $dag){
                    echo "<br>";
                    if (in_array($dag, $notatieDatum))
                    {
                        echo "Match found";
                        print_r ($userNotities);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Match not found";
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please always present your sample array data as `var_export()` text (not `var_dump()`, not `print_r()`, and not `dd()`) so that contributors can use it.

Answer (score -2):

You are using dates as key. Fine, hashmaps are efficient approach but complicated. Even your question is hard to understand. Always try to take simple approach to your solution. Once you get experienced and proficient with technology you are using, so will your ability to use it's tools.

[https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_merge.asp#:~:text=Definition%20and%20Usage,last%20one%20overrides%20the%20others](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_merge.asp#:%7E:text=Definition%20and%20Usage,last%20one%20overrides%20the%20others).

// this is like your example:

https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_func_array_merge2

What you are looking for is a function

```
array_merge($firstArray, $secondArray);
```

which replaces what ever is in first array with data from second array

Comment: This preserves the values from the first array (with dates) -- which is not desired in the output.

Comment: I'm confused. In desired output you are listing elements from first array.

Comment: All keys from the first array are represented in the output, if a given key is not represented in the second array, then its value needs to default to an empty array (or a single empty element array).